# Crackling noise after first gear clutch

Tags: clutch, noise

I hear a crackling noise after I get to my biting point @ First Gear. I have heard of this noise before but not in all the cars. My car has only done 43000 miles to the clock and has a good condition. Although it's a 1.1L car (i.e. it's gonna move like a slug), the crackling noise is not a normal thing right?

Comment: What is the make, model and year of your car?

Comment: Mitsubishi Colt CZI 3-door (2007) 1.1L

Comment: Did you get this resolved? If so, we'd love to hear about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be my drive belt. I replaced it, costed it quite a lot from Halfords. The car is gone due to an accident recently, but that is unrelated to this problem. THe issue was fixed after I replaced the drive belt. Usually 43k-44k is the standard change time for fan belts I think.

Comment: Glad to hear that the accident was not because of the drive, those are nasty crashes;)

Comment: @hagubear   It looks like your answer was saved before you finished it.  Could you go back and edit the answer and finish it?  Interested in what it was.  Also, award yourself the answer by hitting the check under the vote arrows.    :)